# Converting Pinescript structure into Amibroker

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, amibroker

I was trying to convert a simple Pinescript condition with data structure to Amibroker AFL.

Amibroker doesn't support structures, and so I am at a loss how to write a similar logic with respect to the Pinescript code.

Any help/guidance/support help will be deeply appreciated.

```
type tre 
    int   bCC
    float bC8
    int   sCC

bar b = bar.new()
var tre C = tre.new()

con = b.c < b.c[4]
```

Comment: Create multiple variables? `C_bCC`, `C_bC8`, `C_sCC` should cover all the cases for `C`.

Comment: @vitruvius Could you please give me an example how to construct it with respect to the snippet.

Comment: Also, there is no concept of '.' [dot] extensions in Amibroker.

Comment: I cannot because I am not familiar with Amibroker. You don't need the dot because you won't be referencing any struct object. You will directly reference the variable. For example, `C.bCC` will be `C_bCC`.

Comment: I see. Amibroker AFL shares some syntax and concepts with C and C++, such as variable declarations, if statements, for loops, and functions.

Could you please elaborate the condition "con = b.c < b.c[4]" and how might I rewrite it. Any pointers is welcome.